# Keep Log10[] in result

Tags: replacement, output-formatting

I want to work using `Log10[...]` yet it keeps reformatting to `Log[...]/Log[10]`.

This simple example can be avoided by using `$PrePrint = # /. {Log[n_.]/Log[10] :> Defer@Log10[n]} &;` but - in my experience - this doesn't resolve nested Logs, as output by the bottom example, *(1)*

Here is an example (and an example replace manipulation), including what I've tried to resolve it.

```
Clear[x, y, e1, e2];
e1 = Simplify[ Solve[x == Log[2, 10^y], y, Reals][[1, 1, 2]]];
e2 = Evaluate[e1 /. (_a*Log[_b])/Log[10] -> a*Log10[b]] // HoldForm

(* Edit1: (Thanks Michael), the _a should be a_., same for _b *)
```

This still gives `xLog[2]/Log[10]` instead of `xLog10[2]`.

I'm using Wolfram Desktop, if that makes a difference. It shouldn't.  I've tried `Hold` and `Unevaluated` without success.

---

*(1)* When using nested logs the `$PrePrint` doesn't work, in my experience.
For instance,

```
FullSimplify[
  Solve[2^(10^(10^x)) == 10^(10^(10^y)), y, Reals][[1, 1, 2, 1]]
]
```

Comment: Use `//.` instead of `/.`

Comment: Maybe off-topic, maybe not: why do you want to use base-10 logarithms? It is a bit of a school-level prejudice to prefer the number 10 over a more natural base like $e$. If at all possible, I'd recommend looking into how to switch your math to natural logarithms.

Comment: @Roman I was looking for the number of digits in a huge number, so `Log10[]` is the appropriate base to use.  I agree in general, but there are cases where good old base-10 logarithms still have their place!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SetSystemOptions[
  "SimplificationOptions" ->
   {"AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> False}];

e1 = Simplify[Solve[x == Log[2, 10^y], y, Reals][[1, 1, 2]]];
e2 = Evaluate[e1 /. (a_*Log[b_])/Log[10] -> a*Log10[b]]

(*  x Log10[2]  *)
```

Note I corrected the pattern `_a` to `a_` and `_b` to `b_`, assuming the correction is correct.

I would suggest that the following is probably better, unless you do not want all logarithms to the base 10:

```
e2 = Evaluate[e1 /. Log[b_] -> Log[10] Log10[b]]
```

(It's better to have simpler patterns on the LHS of a `Rule`, unless the simpler pattern matches too many expressions.)

The expression still works like a regular logarithm:

```
x Log10[2] // N
(*  0.30103 x  *)
```

---

*Update: Another alternative*

With the `SystemOptions` as above:

```
e1 = Simplify[Solve[x == Log[2, 10^y], y, Reals][[1, 1, 2]]];
e2 = Evaluate[e1 /. Log -> (Log10[#] Log[10] &)]

(*  x Log10[2]  *)
```

A nested example:

```
e1 = Log[Log[x]/Log[10]]/Log[10];
e2 = Evaluate[e1 /. Log -> (Log10[#] Log[10] &)]

(*  Log10[Log10[x]]  *)
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael for the suggestion, (and for fixing my _a !!).  The SystemOption does indeed prevent ln() expansion.  Unfortunately this does not reduce the nested log case.  [this image](https://imgur.com/CcftgCv) illustrates the desired result, but I'm looking for a generic replacement.  As I worded the question poorly I will accept this answer if a generic solution is not forthcoming.

Comment: @AndrewMalcolm See the update for an alternative. Another way would be to use `//.` instead of `/.`, but you'd have to alter the pattern to exclude `Log[10]` from replacement.

Answer (score 3):

```
e1 /. Log[x_ /; x != 10] -> Defer[Log10[x]]/Log10[E]

(*    x Log10[2]    *)
```

or

```
e1 /. Log[x_ /; x != 10] -> Inactive[Log10][x]/Log10[E]
```

[image]

depending on your use case.

For the second, more complex, example, we need to be a bit more careful:

- we need a [repeated replacement](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) `//.`,
- we cannot [defer the evaluation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Defer.html) and must use the [inactive form](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) instead, and
- we must check for [strict inequality](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnsameQ.html) from 10 with `=!=`:

```
f = Log[Log[Log[2^10^10^x]/Log[10]]/Log[10]]/Log[10];

f //. Log[x_ /; x =!= 10] -> Inactive[Log10][x]/Log10[E]
```

[image]

Which does what the OP requested but isn't as simple as `Log10[10^x + Log10[Log10[2]]]` could be.